# viewing underlying value in access lookup field

Tags: ms-access

If I have a lookup field in Access with the first (bound) column hidden by setting field widths to 0";1", is there a way to see the real underlying value of the field without having to change the formatting of the lookup column?

Comment: Yes, though can you clarify how you want to "see" the value?  Or perhaps give an explanation as to why you want to see if and we can give you some suggestions.

Comment: @Newd I had a lookup from a table, and two of the records in the related table happened to have the same value for the visible field in the related table (a rare occurrence), and I was debugging a problem in a different query and wanted to know which record the lookup referred to. I guess I could change the format of the table temporarily, or make a query to reveal the other fields of the records, but it seemed like an overkill to just find out what record it was referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there is a very simple way to do it. In the query, go to field properties and click on the "Lookup" tab, and choose textbox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to access the available values without editing the lookup column.

With that said, I would point out the following:

Changing the formatting of the lookup column only impacts 2 things.

1. When you navigate the records from the table view you will see the new definition.
2. Any forms created in the future will now inherit the new definition.

In other words, changing the formatting of the lookup column doesn't impact any forms you may have already created based upon that field.

You can have a more descriptive description in your table that is completely separate from the definition in your forms.

If you want to know all of the values I suggest that you edit the drop down to show a concatenation of columns 1 and 2.

For example, lets say you had a value list of

```
1;foo;2;bar
```

The value list could be changed to

```
1;1-foo;2;2-bar
```

Then you know at a glance what the "hidden" field value represents.  (The same could be done if the record source is a query.)

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear - I meant in a table, not in a form.